# Responsive layout on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-constraintlayout

I have three elements in layout, two TextViews and one ImageView between them. I'm trying to achieve this behavior:

1. image (arrow) has 9patch
2. image is wide as possible
3. image has set minimal width
4. right and left texts go wider with longer text but only to meet image's minWidth, then new line appears

Below are few screenshots from Android Studio layout preview, gained with different layouts.

[image]
[image]
[image]

What I have tried:

- Relative layout: image centered, minWidth set, texts have set toRightOf/toLeftOf
- Relative layout: image has set toRightOf/toLeftOf
- Constraint layout: "constraint arrows" go from image to text
- Constraint layout: "constraint arrows" go from text to image
- Linear layout: using weight (not really responsive)

What I always get:

[image]

What I want seems quite straightforward to me but I cannot do it. Am I missing something or is it really impossible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is code whcih you tried

Comment: Well, I was thinking about attaching some code, but I have tried many possibilities - it would be hard to choose the one or all. But, if you look to answers, you can see 2/5 main attempts :-)
My question is not "what is wrong with this code" but "how to achieve this".

Comment: Hi bro, I found something you might like. [FlexBoxLayout Tutorial](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html) and [FlexBoxLayout Github Page](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_tv"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_tv"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Replace your image with `arrow`

Comment: This is the second point from list "what I have tried". This makes exactly what is on the image "what I always get".

Comment: @JerabekJakub Set maxWidth to both TextView with some some dp, like `android:maxWidth="100dp"`

Comment: That helps a little, but i does not make layout responsive.

Comment: @JerabekJakub What does you mean by by responsive? If you want to say to say different width in landscape and portate then set minimumwidth to imageview only. and remove maxwidth from both textview

Comment: @JerabekJakub Like use 'android:minWidth="100dp"` to ImageView and remove android:maxWidth="100dp" from both text views. It will help to get available width in both orientations

Comment: responsive = image (arrow) is larger (wider) when text is short and image is shorter when text is longer but only to specified width. Check the three images in question. Orientation does not matter, application is portrait only.

Comment: My last solution will work in this case. Set minimum width to image view.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more answer done via constraintLayout by creating horizontal chains.

**Updated as you asked**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_tv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ajn sdhbch chf nbhjgvbf vkjf vhf bvihfijnvj vfknvv ihvb jnvkjnfv kjnvfn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_tv"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_tv"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_next_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_tv"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Looks promising, but this is the result: http://imgur.com/a/5WPoO long texts are not devided into more lines and overflows into each other.

Comment: Then change textview `layout_height` to `layout_height="0dp"`, i.e. to match the parent size. result is something like this. [imgur.com/QpIomI5](http://imgur.com/QpIomI5)

Comment: Please update your answer, only this change does not work for me.

Comment: Have updated the answer by making `layout_width` as `0dp` and sorry its `layout_width` not `layout_height` as I mentioned before.

Comment: Thanks. I think that this solutiion is so far the best. But it is still not what I want - image is not scalled when texts are short. This is the reason why I will not accept your answer. But thank you anyway, I have at least upvoted your answer.

Comment: Now the only solution i see is the solution given @Pankaj Kumar with setting the left and right textview `maxwidth` programmatically by calculating the (window size width)/2 - (imageview minwidth)/2. But i will still stop the textview size at around half of the screen.

Comment: This might help you. [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:** the code is updated for more responsive layout.

Now play with `maxwidth` of both text views.

For your problem updating `maxwidth` programmatically will be better.

This code is done with Linear layout method. There is a `GridLayout` method also along with `constraintLayout` method. Can be achieved with many layouts, if you know the right technique to do so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView is long and very long" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_circle_green" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="60dp"
        android:text="TextView is long and very long" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is the fifth point from list "what I have tried". This makes left and right columns same size, which exactly the opposite of world "responsive".

Comment: Nope, still the same. When you use weight, these elements will have still the same width. I need them to be flexible with short/long text.