# How to align 2 images left and right inside LinearLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show two images by side by side below of google map.Image showing is working. But the image showing the same side. I want to show some text middle of the 2 two images.

[image]

The 2nd image I want to show in right side of the view, and the text in middle.

Current code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/bt_white">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="@string/action_settings"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bt_white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="First Text View"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Second Text view"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is how it looks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add gravity `center` and `weightSum` with weights for `LinearLayout` as in

```
 <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity ="center" //--- add this
        android:weightSum =" 3" //--add this
        android:background="@color/bt_white">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight = "1" //---add this
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp" //--0
            android:layout_weight = "1" //---add this
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="@string/action_settings"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_weight = "1" //---add this
            android:layout_width="0dp"  //-- make it to zero
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome :) Glad it helped

Comment: adding weight will change the size of images, which is not acceptable i think

Comment: That is optional, we can still set them to center using gravity and if we width of images which are rendering we can force them to fit using hard coded width

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Done by passing weights.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/action_settings"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: adding weight will change the size of images, which is not acceptable i think

Comment: I have answered it before check this out [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855955/responsive-layout-on-android/45875990#45875990).
There are two answers by me. see what suits your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

replace your .xml with below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/bt_white">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="@string/action_settings"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have multiple textviews in center

Comment: adding weight will change the size of images, which is not acceptable i think.

Answer (score 0):

```
/***You can use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout****/



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/action_settings"/>

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using RelativeLayout like following-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ndroid:background="#fff">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="@string/action_settings"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="@string/action_settings"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```